# What is a jQuery UI alternative to a select box with 500,000 options?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I have a production app that tracks a product catalog. Some customers have huge amounts of products. The app was originally built for smaller numbers of products. As a result, I have select boxes in a few places that absolutely do not work for these customers with lots of products.

What sort of UI element from jQuery can I employ that will allow the selection of a product from a very large list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if its really jQuery UI you want, then the [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) control comes closest

there are variations like the [autocomplete with combobox](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox)
which might be a good solution for you

Answer (score 12):

I like [Chosen.js](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/). It's pretty slick. It's not a jQuery UI component, but it doesn't conflict.

If you're stuck on using jQuery UI for this, I've also had some luck with the [jQuery UI SelectMenu plugin](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/). It doesn't have all the features of Chosen, but it at least presents information better a standard select box and is style-able.

Comment: chosen *is* sleek indeed! +1 for great suggestion

Answer (score 4):

[**Autocomplete.**](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete) It is part of jQuery UI toolset which makes it nice if you are trying to only have a few JS libs.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [jQuery UI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).

Answer (score 3):

Unobtrusive Fast-filter Dropdown is the best one, as it can handle a rally large number of options, I had a similar issue. I used this [plugin](http://code.google.com/p/ufd/)

Here is the approach to design this [plugin](http://blog.toolman.geek.nz/2010/03/infix-search-using-trie-data-structure.html)

If you ever tested in IE, Autocomplete will throw an error "the script is running" something of that sort..

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SelectBoxIt](http://www.selectboxit.com), a jQueryUI plugin I created to replace the standard HTML select box.

It should work very well for long dropdown lists since I specifically focused on performance for select boxes with thousands of options.  Keyboard search and navigation support is also provided.